exporting pdf via highcharts that have some Hebrew characters
I am using C# .net 4 framework 4.8 with javascript - highcharts version 8.0.0
I want to export pdf file, but I am encountering a problem in Hebrew characters, which replaced by gibberish characters.
As I found out, add a wrapper file highcharts-post-offline.js:
    Highcharts.wrap(Highcharts.Chart.prototype, 'exportChartLocal', function (proceed, options, chartOptions) {
    // Check if exporting as PDF
    if (options && options.type === 'application/pdf') {
        // Set default font to Arial in jsPDF
        if (typeof jsPDF !== 'undefined') {
            window.jspdf = jsPDF;
            jsPDF.API.events.push(['addFonts', function () {
                const fonts = [
                    { name: 'David', style: 'normal', file: '../fonts/David/David.ttf' },
                    { name: 'David', style: 'bold', file: '../fonts/David/David-bold.ttf' }
                ]
                const fontPromises = fonts.map(font =>
                    //                const fontUrl = '../fonts/Arialx.ttf'; // URL to the font file
                    fetch(font.file)
                        .then(response => {
                            if (!response.ok) {
                                throw new Error('Font file not found: ' + font.file); // Handles non-200 responses
                            }
                            return response.arrayBuffer()
                        })
                        .then(buffer => {
                            // Convert ArrayBuffer to Base64
                            let fontBase64 = arrayBufferToBase64(buffer);

                            // Add the Base64-encoded font to the jsPDF VFS
                            if (!jsPDF.API.VFS) { // no particular sense for this code. it is not updated.
                                jsPDF.API.VFS = {};
                            }
                            this.addFileToVFS(`${font.name}-${font.style}.ttf`, fontBase64);
                            this.addFont(`${font.name}-${font.style}.ttf`, font.name, font.style);
                        })
                        .catch(error => {
                            console.error('Error loading font:', error)
                        })
                );
                Promise.all(fontPromises).then(() => {
                    this.setFont('David', 'normal'); // Set default font once all are loaded
                });
            }]);
        }
    }

    // Call the original function
    proceed.call(this, options, chartOptions);
});

function arrayBufferToBase64(buffer) {
    let binary = '';
    const bytes = new Uint8Array(buffer);
    for (let i = 0; i < bytes.byteLength; i++) {
        binary += String.fromCharCode(bytes[i]);
    }
    let res = window.btoa(binary);
    return res;
}

Also I added the David fonts file from windows (ttf files).
And change the Bundle to this (BundleConfig.cs):
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/highcharts").Include(
    "~/Scripts/highcharts.js",
    "~/Scripts/exporting.js",
    "~/Scripts/highcharts-setup.js",
    "~/Scripts/offline-exporting.js",
    "~/Scripts/highcharts-post-offline.js",
    "~/Scripts/drilldown.js",
    "~/Scripts/no-data-to-display.js",
    "~/Scripts/highcharts-3d.js",
    "~/Scripts/highcharts-more.js",
    "~/Scripts/histogram-bellcurve.js"));

In highcharts-setup.js:
Highcharts.setOptions(Highcharts.merge({
    lang: {
        decimalPoint: ',',
        thousandsSep: '.',
        rtl: true  // Right-to-left direction setting for Hebrew
    },
    chart: {
        style: {
            fontFamily: 'Arial, Tahoma, sans-serif'
        }
    },
    exporting: {
        fallbackToExportServer: false
    }
}, Highcharts.getOptions()));

Still, any pdf I try to download, is in gibberish characters instead of Hebrew characters.
(It is OK for png, jpg, and any other file can be exported via highcharts).

You need to ensure that the fonts are correctly loaded, pls double-check the paths to your font-siles in highcharts-post-offline.js. After loading set the font to the desired one and check if they're displayed correct before exporting .
